# How to find the partial derivative of compound function by MATLAB？

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, the variable of g1 is the delta(t). Why is the partial derivative 0?

```
%% Matlab
syms delta(t) g1(delta) 

diff(g1,delta(t))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], i.e. include the definition of `g1` and `delta`

Comment: @Wolfie Just want to see the result of symbolic operation

Comment: what you want to do is this instead: `diff(g1(delta), delta)` which gives: `diff(g1(delta(t)), delta(t))`